Adverb for Lore?
In terms of stories, movies, or in this particular case- Superheroes. Canon is verified fact, Lore is fan/audience conjecture and theory. Canon's adjective is Canonical, the adverb is Canonically. Lore's adjective is Loral/Loreal. What is the adverb?

Your definitions are not quite right. You're correct that canon is verified fact (details included in published pieces of fiction about characters or the world. These details must have been published by the author (e.g., Stephen King) or by the company that owns the franchise (e.g., Marvel).
But Lore is actually better defined as non-plot details about the world. E.g., details about a superhero's sister might be lore if she isn't highly relevant to the plot. Lore can be either canonical, or fan-work

If you're willing to accept loral or loreal as adjectives, you can add -ly to the end of almost any adjective to get an adverb. The problem is, they're not usual adjectives.

Please give an example sentence showing how you'd use this word.  Some words don't like being used adverbially.  You could end up with something morphologically "correct" but the phrase  could sound like it was written by someone who didn't have a feel for English.

I don't think it's correct to use loral or loreal for "franchise lore". Lore, in addition to "backstory"/"accumulated knowledge of a subject" is a body part in animals:

the surface of the head of a bird between the eyes and the base of the bill
the corresponding area in a snake or fish

And most of the uses of loral or loreal are about "loral stripes" or other anatomical descriptions.
For the fandom sense, I don't think there's an adjective or adverb. Something like lore-wise or lore reason might be the closest? But you'd usually say something like "according to the lore".

She's canonically more powerful than Superman.
According to the lore, she's more powerful than Superman.
Lore-wise, she's more powerful than Superman.
The canonical reason she has powers is a gamma ray burst.
In the lore, the reason she has powers is a gamma ray burst.
The lore reason she has powers is a gamma ray burst.

As Friendly Racoon says, lore isn't typically fan conjecture. Lore is background details, either explained in the original work or in supplementary materials, though it might be compiled by fans. In fandom or 'fannish' places, you might use the term fanon (fan + canon, adj. fanonical, adv. fanonically or in fanon) to describe popularly-accepted fan theories, and a person's personal theory might be called a headcanon.
(All of these terms are informal and might be used differently in different places, of course.)

Headcanon is generally only understood by serious, serious fans. But it is definitely a phrase and it is definitely one way to articulate what the OP wants. "I HC that ..." is an abbreviation.

"lore isn't typically fan conjecture" Slight nuance: lore can include an aggregation of multiple sources which can include fan conjecture even if it isn't particularly confirmed - it just hasn't been explicitly disproven either. For example, I could refer to "vampire lore" which isn't referring to a particular story but rather to the amalgamation of what generally constitutes a vampire across multiple sources/authors/usages in common media. This can include fan conjecture, at least if there's a reasonable claim to it being generally agreed upon by a sufficient amount of people.

The word 'lorewise' is used on various fan forums. If you Google it, the top entries are several Reddit pages asking how powerful a character is "lorewise".
Technically though, the opposite of canonical is apocryphal, defined as "(of a story or statement) of doubtful authenticity, although widely circulated as being true". You probably know that 'canon' mainly refers to the 66 books of the Bible agreed as being authentic. Some other related writings are collected as The Apocrypha, and while not accepted as authentic some feel they have some historical value. Basically Christian fanfic. "Widely circulated as true" could describe some of the fictional 'lore' you refer to, but 'apocryphal' tends to carry a negative inference.

I suspect that most standard English speakers may not grasp the difference between canon and lore. So, if you want to be absolutely clear to someone who isn't a serious fan, I would recommend saying something like, "Many fans agree that Superman ..."
Kaia is absolutely correct that in fandom, fanon and headcanon are accepted and recognized terms that are potentially appropriate. Remember that headcanon is your own view on things, which others may or may not share. Also, you can say "I HC that Superman ...", that is, abbreviating headcanon and then turning it into a verb. These terms are, as Kaia says, informal. More specifically, they're part of the community's jargon that would not make sense in standard English without explanation.
